# pass escapechar to newcommand inside listing

Tags: macros, listings

i have defined a new command for colored bold text as follows to use in `listing` environment:

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,0.8,0}
\newcommand{\lstemph}[1]{\textcolor{mycolor}{#1}}
```

In my `\lstdefinestyle`, there is an option provided: `escapechar=!`, and everytime i want to use my command, i have to write `!` before and after the command:

```
return !\lstemph{tmp\_val + 2}!;
```

How can I define the command to include the escape char, so I must not write the `!` in the `listing`?

Update: my sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,0.8,0}
\newcommand{\lstemph}[1]{\textcolor{mycolor}{#1}}
\lstloadlanguages{C++}
\lstdefinestyle{myCpp}
{
    language=C++,
    tabsize = 4,
    framesep = 3mm,
    frame=tb,   
    classoffset = 0,    
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \bfseries\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle = \itshape\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
    stringstyle = \color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    extendedchars = true,
    breaklines = true,
    prebreak = \textrightarrow,
    postbreak = \textleftarrow,
    escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)},
    escapechar=!,
    moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@},
    numbers = left,
    numberstyle = \tiny,
    stepnumber = 5
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myCpp,caption={Test}]
return !\lstemph{tmp\_val + 2}!;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: hi, i updated the example

Comment: Thanks. The crucial point here is that it's the escape char which lets `listings` recognize `\lstemph` to be command to be executed and not to be typeset literally.

Comment: Yes i know that, and wonder if there is anyway to make a new command/macro which is equivalent to the whole !\lstemph{}! ?

Comment: I fear you're out of look unless changing `listings` internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your command accepts only one argument and you'll never need to pass ending curly brace (`}`) to it, then you can "emulate" a command in listings by appropriate use of `moredelim` key:

```
moredelim=[is][\lstemph]{\\lstemph\{}{\}}
```

If you use your `escapechar` only to input `\lstemph` command, then you could simply use `!` as delimiter:

```
moredelim=[is][\lstemph]{!}{!}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,0.8,0}
\newcommand{\lstemph}[1]{\textcolor{mycolor}{#1}}
\lstloadlanguages{C++}
\lstdefinestyle{myCpp}
{
    language=C++,
    tabsize = 4,
    framesep = 3mm,
    frame=tb,   
    classoffset = 0,    
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \bfseries\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle = \itshape\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
    stringstyle = \color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    extendedchars = true,
    breaklines = true,
    prebreak = \textrightarrow,
    postbreak = \textleftarrow,
    escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)},
    % escapechar=!,
    moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@},
    numbers = left,
    numberstyle = \tiny,
    stepnumber = 5
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myCpp,caption={Test},moredelim={[is][\lstemph]{\\lstemph\{}{\}}}]
return \lstemph{tmp_val + 2};
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myCpp,caption={Test},moredelim={[is][\lstemph]{!}{!}}]
return !tmp_val + 2!;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: print screen of two resulting listings]

Comment: `prebreak` and `postbreak` don't work anymore, so long lines are not auto-broken, however, my question was solved! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian pointed out in his comment, what you're asking is not possible. It is akin to asking:

> In [some C language], how can I print a newline by writing `n` instead of `\n`?

One way or another, you need to specify what needs to be interpreted as TeX rather than as literal text. The only way to do that with `listings` is via its escape-character mechanism.